# pgAdmin shortcuts to execute scripts

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Who knows pgAdmin shortcuts to execute scripts in pgAdmin Query tool? Namely to execute whole query and execute current script.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120380/keyboard-shortcut-to-execute-statement-at-cursor-in-pgadmin

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Select the relevant portion and hit the <kbd>F5</kbd> key in the SQL editor of pgAdmin.
OR use the "Execute query" button (green arrow) in the toolbar.
If nothing is selected, the whole script is executed.

Comment: in sql developer (for oracle), it will automatically only execute the current sql block, as delineated with semi colons. Is there anyway to do this in pgadmin? So annoying to constantly be selecting query portions

Comment: @Not that I would know of. Being used to the current behavior I would not fancy this mode. You could ask for such an option on the [pgadmin-support](http://www.pgadmin.org/support/) list ...

Comment: is it possible to execute the whole script line by line?

Comment: @wutzebaer: Not that I would know.

Answer (score 4):

on mac use the fn key (bottom left) + F5

Answer (score 3):

shortcuts to execute scripts

`F5` for windows user and

`control` + `E` for mac user

Comment: Ctrl + E works for windows as well (select the query & Ctrl E)

Answer (score 1):

`F5` works on Mac and Windows.

Highlighting just part of the script executes just that part of the script.

List of all keyboard shortcut Query Tools for pgAdmin 4 is in the [docs](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html#query-tool)

`control`+ `e` didn't work on my Mac.

Comment: F5 works, but it's quite annoying on mac (as you need to press fn with this, and they are quite far apart). What I did personally, is to change shortcut from F5 to shift + enter in `preferences -> query tool -> keyboard shortcuts -> execute query`

Answer (score 0):

In(Windows PC) PostgreSQL, pgadmin has some issues in its layouts.  Sometimes shortcut keys won't work (eg:- ctrl + / is using for line comments, but it won't work).  I experienced this problem (a annoying one).  Finally, I solved this problem by resetting its layout.

Layout Reset.

open PostgreSQL pgadmin -> click tab File -> select Reset Layout.

Problem solved.